# How to make Inno Setup ignore the hidden attribute while searching for files?

Tags: inno-setup, hidden

I have to copy into the installer folders containing hidden files (in my case Desktop.ini).

I use a line similar to this one in the [Files] section:

```
Source: "folder\*desktop.ini"; DestDir: "{app}\folder"; Flags: recursesubdirs uninsneveruninstall; Attribs: hidden
```

This line only works if I remove the hidden attributes. If all are hidden, it complains that it could not find any files.

How can I configure Inno to search for hidden files using patterns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't, at present. If you have a look at the source of [*Compile.pas*](http://cvs.jrsoftware.org/view/issrc/Projects/Compile.pas?view=markup) and search for the `BuildFileList()` procedure you will find that for wildcard source directories hidden files are ignored when the file list is built:

```
if SourceIsWildcard then begin
  if FindData.dwFileAttributes and FILE_ATTRIBUTE_HIDDEN <> 0 then
    Continue;
  FileName := FindData.cFileName;
end
```

If you have Delphi you could of course simply remove this check and rebuild the compiler.